# Using my TUI tool in a subshell or pipe "steals" the stdout. How can I delay a write to a pipe so that my TUI can use the terminal first?

Tags: go, terminal, io, pipe, termios

I'm writing a simple TUI in Go from scratch, it puts the terminal into Raw mode (non-canonical mode) and turns off echoing, then it interprets user input, draws a TUI and shows an image based on that input.

My issue is that when I build the binary and run it in a subshell or a pipe-chain, the  stdout is swallowed up by the pipe and the subshell and nothing is displayed. Without a pipe or subshell it runs as expected.

**expected behavior:**

I want/expect the behavior to act similar to

```
x=$(fd | fzf)
printf "%s\n" "${x}"
```

In this example fd (find alternative) spits out a list of files that are fed to fzf, which then properly displays its interface on the terminal (despite being in a subshell or pipe) and x is assigned to that output.

How can I delay a write to a pipe/subshell until my TUI exits? or how can I prevent the pipe/subshell from "eating" the stdout so that I can use the stdout of /dev/tty until I am ready to write into the pipe?

(please note that I am ***not*** talking about os.Pipe, or the os/exec package, I am talking about interfacing with terminal I/O operations in Golang)
I dont think code examples are necessary in this case but if you must see what exactly I am working on then I will leave these here:
https://github.com/sweetbbak/catnip/tree/main/go-catnip and https://github.com/sweetbbak/suwudo/blob/main/main.go

Comment: The answer is: use STDERR to render the TUI and NOT Stdout. this is what Fzf and Bubbletea do as of 2022. I dont think there is another way around it since subshells/pipes eat stdout. I thought you could defer that connection until needed but Im not sure about that. Stderr is an easy solution to this TUI problem